# Google Calendar API Python - Import Multiple Events

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-calendar-api

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290984/google-calendar-api-insert-multiple-events-in-python) guide, but the code below

```python
event1 = events[0]
event2 = events[1]
event =  service.events().import_(calendarId='blah@group.calendar.google.com', body=event1).execute()
event =  service.events().import_(calendarId='blah@group.calendar.google.com', body=event2).execute()
```

In which events is an array of my events, seems to overwrite the first event, once I try to import the second event. If I just run the first event declaration, the event is added, but once I add in the second one, it overwrites the first one, and just shows the second one.

Comment: Won't using the same variable name (you use 'event' for both event1 and event2) over-write? That's the expected behaviour, is it not?

Comment: Makes sense to me, but that guide I linked is doing it that way, so I assumed that was the correct way to add multiple events.

Comment: The guide you linked to uses the _events().insert_ method while you appear to be using the _events().import_ method.

Comment: When I use insert, I get this error. "The requested identifier already exists." Import works, it just overwrites any previous events.

Answer (score 0):

Execute returns an event resource

```
event =  service.events().import_(calendarId='blah@group.calendar.google.com', body=event1).execute()
```

the event variable will now equal the event resource for event1.

```
event =  service.events().import_(calendarId='blah@group.calendar.google.com', body=event2).execute()
```

the event variable will now equal the event resource for event2.

If you want the result back then i suggest you change the response variable names to something like event1Response and event2Response.

Comment: Execute is what the docs tay to do [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import#code-sample), but I don't need anything returned to me. I just want to import multiple events?

Comment: then run it twice

Comment: When I run it twice, the second event overwrites the first event. If I run it once, the first event shows up.

Comment: You know, I think it is because of this uid being the same for every event. "iCalUID": "originalUID" I have no idea how to generate a different uid for every event...

Answer (score 0):

Yea, so you need a unique icaluid, otherwise Google Calendar will erase any other event that has that uid. I simply imported time, and used time.time() for the icaluid.